# Reverse engineer database from an Oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, reverse-engineering

I would like to know if there is any tool able to extract the design from an existing Oracle database.

I have a read access to it and I would like to have the design. Or simply export it to a *.sql and then read it with any tool able to create the design with the links between the tables.
Something like that [image: alt database design sample]
<sub>(source: [fileguru.com](http://www.fileguru.com/images/b/database_design_studio___lite__dds_lite__business_information_database-9552.jpeg))</sub>

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle SQL Data Modeler answered to all my questions.

It has a reverse engineering tool that creates the logical and physical model from the database.

Answer (score 8):

There are a number of tools which do reverse engineering from an Oracle database, but most require a license.

Oracle has [its own Data Modeller](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html).  Previously Oracle tried to charge an exorbitant licence fee but obviously they had few takers because it is now free.  It is not a great product but it does a decent job on reverse engineering.

If you are a site which uses TOAD then you should definitely consider [Quest's TOAD Data Modeler](http://www.quest.com/toad-data-modeler/).  The additional cost is not a great stretch from the basic TOAD fee.

There are not many other free tools left on the market but SQL Power offer a community edition of their SQL Architect tool which does reverse engineering.  [Check it out](http://www.sqlpower.ca/page/whyarchitect).

Comment: Thank you but as I said above, the tool I used is from oracle and for free. I just downloaded it from there website.

Comment: It is free. I just downloaded it. Go to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/downloads/datamodeler-087275.html . Click on the download you want. Login with any account. I have a free account. See this tutorial on how to use it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=numjatrl4So