# Trace a path between Oracle tables?

Tags: oracle, join

Can I use Oracle sys tables to trace a path between two table, all the possibilities to go from X table to Y table.
The problem is:
I work on an enormous database, where it's really difficult to know rapidly, which tables are vital to make a join between two tables.
Can I do this?

**First Need:**

The problem with SQL Developer Data Modeler and the other tools, is the fact to have to select tables to rev_eng (So I should already know the tables to select) but for me, this is the major problem. In my case I have 800 tables and I can't select them all to trace the path. My desire is to submit as arguments two tables and then generate all the possible paths.

**Second Need :**

I have already try to query sys.all_constraints and the max I've done, is to detect the tables directly connected to a table X.
The query:

```
SELECT C1.TABLE_NAME,C2.TABLE_NAME 
FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS C1, ALL_CONSTRAINTS C2 
WHERE C2.CONSTRAINT_NAME = C1.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME
AND UPPER(C1.OWNER) LIKE '**MY_SCHEMA**'
AND C1.CONSTRAINT_TYPE='R' 
AND UPPER(C1.TABLE_NAME) LIKE '**X**'
ORDER BY C1.TABLE_NAME
```

---

So if somebody can help me to conceive at least the query to have this result:

> **Table1  |  Table2  |  JoinCollumnofTable1  |  JoinCollumnofTable2**

To have that, I surmise the other table to join to **ALL_CONSTRAINTS**  is **ALL_CON_COLUMNS**
But the problem I've found is the composite primary_keys.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reverse engineer database from an Oracle database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474107/reverse-engineer-database-from-an-oracle-database)

Answer (score 3):

This is why Nature gave us data models: to assist in tasks like this.

If you don't have a data model then you can reverse engineer one from the data dictionary.  See my answer to [a question on reverse engineering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3474278/146325).

Reverse engineering can only identify relationships which have been defined by foreign keys.  This shouldn't need stating but let's say it anyway: if your database hasn't got constraints you have *no chance* of deriving a data model automatically.

> "I have 800 tables and I can't select them all to trace the path. "

Hmmm, I suppose recommending you reverse engineer a data model is a bit like the punchline to the old joke about how to get to Cork: "Well I wouldn't start from here".  The whole point about having a data model upfront is that we have it when when we really need it.

Comment: Can you read my last edtion of this post, and realy thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

If primary and foreign key relationships are established in the database, you can use a tool like Oracle Developer with Data Modeler to reverse engineer the model and give a graphical representation of what the relationships are.

Tools like this read the Oracle dictionary to determine the relationships between tables. You can do this yourself by querying views such as sys.all_constraints.

I cobbled the following query together using [Tim Hall's Generic Function Using a Ref Cursor](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php), since I only have 10g here (you can use 11g's LISTAGG function if you've got 11g). It should get you close.

```
SELECT ac1.table_name "Table", ac2.table_name "Referencing Table"
     , concatenate_list(CURSOR(SELECT acc.column_name 
                                 FROM all_cons_columns acc 
                                WHERE acc.constraint_name = ac1.constraint_name
                                  AND acc.owner = 'the_owner'
                                ORDER BY position)) "PK Columns"
     , concatenate_list(CURSOR(SELECT acc.column_name 
                                 FROM all_cons_columns acc 
                                WHERE acc.constraint_name = ac2.constraint_name
                                  AND acc.owner = 'the_owner'
                                ORDER BY position)) "FK Columns"
  FROM all_constraints ac1 JOIN all_constraints ac2 
                             ON ac1.constraint_name = ac2.r_constraint_name
 WHERE ac1.table_name = 'your_table'
   AND ac1.owner = 'the_owner'
   AND ac2.owner = 'the_owner'
   AND ac1.constraint_type = 'P';
```

Comment: Can you read my last edtion of this post, and realy thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Also try schemaspy - an open source free alternative which uses the foreign keys to generate a relationship model!

Comment: Can you read my last edtion of this post, and realy thank you for the answer!

Comment: Awsome Tool, the most appropriate to my case.
The point is you can give a table in parameter to have specific informations.